# RenderFlex overflowed on the right of custom widget

Tags: flutter

I am working in a custom widget.

It should have a row with a FlatButton and an horizontal ListView.

This is the current output:

[image]

My latest target is to get something like this:

[image]

But prior to include the user's image and name, I need to solve the issue of the RenderFlex overflowed on the right.

Here you have my current code for the widget:

```
Widget _usuarios() {
  return Container(
    height: 105,
    width: double.infinity,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: null,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          child: Image.asset('assets/images/buscar_usuario.png'),
        ),
        ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("item 1"),
            Text("item 2"),
            Text("item 3"),
            Text("item 4"),
            Text("item 1"),
            Text("item 2"),
            Text("item 3"),
            Text("item 4"),
            Text("item 1"),
            Text("item 2"),
            Text("item 3"),
            Text("item 4"),
            Text("item 1"),
            Text("item 2"),
            Text("item 3"),
            Text("item 4"),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

I don't want the button to scroll with the list.  I would prefer to let the button always visible while the app user can scroll through the user's list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with Expanded will resolve your problem.

```
     Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
        ),
      ),
```

Your ListView acquiring the width as much as it wants. By wrapping it inside Expanded Widget, it will specify the width of the list view or giving it the constraint to fill only the remaining width.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this you can use [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html). Expanded can expand a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so that the child fills the available space.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: FlatButton()),
    Expanded(
        flex: 8,
        child: ListView()),
  ],
);
```

here flex is the amount of space the children can occupy.